# Inaccessible_boot_device installing Windows 10 in Thunderbolt m2 NVME drive on iMac

Tags: windows, ssd, imac, thunderbolt

I am trying (for 3 days now) to install Windows 10 on a new Thunderbolt 3 NVME m2 drive. I already have a SATA SSD on a USB 3.0 enclosure, with Windows 10 OS running without any problem. So, the first thing I tried was to clone my drive, but I got this inaccessible boot device BSOD.

I also tried using Wintousb - with the same result. Then I tried using a wininstall USB stick and tried to install Windows 10 with the Thunderbolt drive as the destination file, but got a

> couldn't create a new partition or find an existing one

so I tried the diskpart commands with no luck. I even found a solution that required changing BIOS settings, but I assumed that this is not a solution for Mac computers.

I really don't know what else to try, or where am I failing...

Comment: Try the solution listed here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74977/is-it-possible-to-install-and-boot-windows-on-a-thunderbolt-drive

Comment: I am not sure what some parts of the tutorial mean, he is using an older version of VMware fusion, and the commands he post wont result in the files he refers to later on, also I don't understand what and how is supposed to be edited in the last part of the tutorial, isn't there any better explained tutorial? please help

Answer (score 1):

I got my drive to run windows by disconnecting it and plugging it back during windows startup, apparently this causes windows to recognize the disk and boot normally.
Is there a way around this? can I get to boot without needing to do this?